# I want to put the Rails application on reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've Linux Server with CentOS 7 OS and I've installed the following application on it.

```
1) Rails 6
2) Ruby 2.6.3p62
```

My requirement now is that I want to put the rails application when starting the server and my application is in / home / chiripapp / app

How can I do that? Please help me

Comment: Are you trying to get the app running locally or deploy it? You mention a linux server, so if you're trying to deploy then you should follow: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/standalone/oss/deploy_app_main.html

Comment: Yes, I want to deploy it.